# Can Eclipse PDT automatically add PHPDoc Blocks to code where needed?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I know most of the java development tools for Eclipse will have a short-cut script for adding in JavaDoc blocks for needed elements (including the page-level).

Further, I know that PDT will allow you to "Generate Element Comment" for many things through the Source menu.

Is there an Eclipse plug-in out there (or perhaps it exists standard in PDT and I've just missed it) that will allow you to add PHPDoc Blocks for all/some of the supported elements in a given file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

place your text cursor right above your function, class or whatever,
type /** and press enter and you'll have a beginning of PHPDoc written.
Eg.

```
/**
 * 
 * Enter description here ...
 * @param unknown_type $book
 * @param unknown_type $product
 */
```

You can then write `@` inside the comments, and use `@` followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to get auto-completion hints for PHPDoc tags.

Answer (score 5):

In PDT 1.3:

Window > Preferences > PHP > Editor > Typing > Automatically close > Phpdoc and comment regions (Check) > Add Phpdoc tags (check)

Also, modify your templates to include more Phpdoc:
Preferences > PHP > Templates